# Queueable Apex - Too many DML Rows: 10001

Tags: apex, batch, queueable-apex

Looking for some help with this.  This class is failing due to the following error: 'Too many DML rows: 10001'.  There's approximately 30,000 thousand records the class is trying to update, but I was hopeful that a Queueable class would be able to handle this update.  Do you think I'll need to use a batch class instead?  Thanks in advance!

```
public with sharing class ArrMeasureLexiaClassicAccountQueueable implements Queueable {
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

    Map<Id, Account> accountmap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    
    List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> subList = [SELECT Id, 
                                                    SBQQ__Account__c, 
                                                    Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c 
                                                    FROM SBQQ__Subscription__c WHERE Status__c = 'Active' AND Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c != 0 AND Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c != null AND SBQQ__Account__r.Is_Lexia_Customer__c = true];


    for (SBQQ__Subscription__c s : subList) {

        if (accountmap.containskey(s.SBQQ__Account__c)) {
            Account a = accountmap.get(s.SBQQ__Account__c);
            a.Lexia_Classic_ARR_Measure__c += s.Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c;
            accountmap.put(s.SBQQ__Account__c, a);
            system.debug('got here');
        }
        else{
            accountmap.put(s.SBQQ__Account__c, new Account (Id = s.SBQQ__Account__c, Lexia_Classic_ARR_Measure__c = s.Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c));
        } 
    }
        update accountmap.values();
}
```

}

Edit: Converted to batch apex per sfdcfox's suggestion:

```
    public with sharing class ArrMeasureLexiaClassicAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public Map<Id, Account> accountmap;
    public String statusValue = 'Active';
    public String accountId = '0011300001hmqpQAAQ';

public ArrMeasureLexiaClassicAccount(){
    accountmap = new Map<Id, Account> ();
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id, SBQQ__Account__c, Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c from SBQQ__Subscription__c where Status__c =: statusValue AND Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c != 0 AND SBQQ__Account__r.Is_Lexia_Customer__c = true AND SBQQ__Account__c =: accountId');
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> scope){

    system.debug('accountMapBeforeAnything:' + accountmap.values());

    for (SBQQ__Subscription__c s : scope) {

    if (accountmap.containskey(s.SBQQ__Account__c)) {
        Account a = accountmap.get(s.SBQQ__Account__c);
        a.Lexia_Classic_ARR_Measure__c += s.Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c;
        accountmap.put(s.SBQQ__Account__c, a);
        system.debug('got here');
    }
    else{
        accountmap.put(s.SBQQ__Account__c, new Account (Id = s.SBQQ__Account__c, Lexia_Classic_ARR_Measure__c = s.Lexia_Classic_ARR_Amount__c));
        system.debug('got to the else');
    } 
     
}

    system.debug('accountMap: ' + accountmap.values());
    update accountmap.values();
}


public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    system.debug('Batch jobs completed.');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queueable classes have [asynchronous limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) (e.g. 60,000ms CPU time), but asynchronous limits won't be higher for SOQL, SOSL, or DML. The main effects of asynchronous limits is increased CPU, callout, and heap size limits. Batchable would be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Thanks as always sfdcfox, I've converted to batch apex.  I'm using Database.Stateful to maintain my 'accountmap' variable across batches.  As a result the processing speed is pretty slow, but it does seem to be doing to trick.